# inserting a tuple into a mysql db

Tags: python, mysql

can anyone show me the syntax for inserting a python tuple/list into a mysql database?
i also need to know if it is possible for user to pass certain rows without inserting anything...
for example: a function is returning this tuple:

```
return job(jcardnum, jreg, jcarddate, jcardtime, jcardserve, jdeliver)
```

suppose the user didnt enter anything in `jreg`
would python itself enter null in to the related row in the DB or would i run in to trouble?

Comment: job isn't a tuple, it's a function.  This question has too little information to give an answer to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a comment says, the `job(...)` part is a function (or class) call -- whatever is returned from that call also gets returned from this `return` statement.

Let's assume it's a tuple. What if "the user didn't enter anything in `jreg`" -- well then, depending on a lot of code you're not showing us, that could be a runtime error (name `jreg` being undefined), an empty string or other initial default value never altered, or `None`; in the latter case that would indeed eventually become a `NULL` in the DB (if acceptable per the DB schema, of course -- otherwise, the DB would reject the insert attempt).

Once you DO finally have a correct and proper tuple `T` that you want to insert,

```
`mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', T)
```

is going to be close to the syntax you want -- if `T` has six items (and `sometable` has six columns, of course).  Each `?` is a placeholder and gets replaced with the corresponding item.  `mycursor` will need to be an instance of Cursor, presumably obtained by some earlier call to `myconnection.cursor` where `myconnection` is an instance of Connection, built by the proper call to `connect` from the DB API module you're using with the right argumentrs.

If you show us about 100 times more code and DB schemas and tell us exactly WHAT you're trying to accomplish, we, collectively speaking, could no doubt be MUCH more useful and specific -- but based on the sub-epsilon amount of info you supply that's about as much as we, collectively speaking, can offer;-).

Comment: +1 for a stunningly complete answer to a partially-asked, and mostly-guessed, question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, cursor.executemany is what you need?

> suppose the user didnt enter anything
>   in jreg would python itself enter null
>   in to the related row in the DB or
>   would i run in to trouble?

I think you should just try, you probably see the warning or error if NULL is not allowed.